# Magento: Product prize is showing zero for all products

Tags: php, magento

In my website all product prizes are showing zero. I didn't set any special prize or grouped prize in product settings. This is my image which shows like this in 90% of products.Currently I'm using Magento 1.9 version.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you created any catalog price rule?

If the price rule is working correctly is show discounted price.
but it is displaying zero means unhandled catalog price rules gives such results.

Comment: There is no catalog price rules

Comment: there might be any module which applies special price and is not working properly so it is showing price as Zero.
Check the module in app/code folder if it is there any.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked **Cart Price Rules** and **Catalog Price Rules**? Also, check **SALES >> GST** rules.

Since, your price has a strikethrough behaviour in the checkout page, it should be **promotions** rules. Have a good look under the both rules.

Comment: Did you check this link [link](http://k2xl.com/wordpress/custom-options-broken-in-magento-1-7-heres-the-fix/)?

This one is for Magento 1.7 but you can check if this is same for you as well. Check for any modules (not the default ones) and also check your files in your themes? Try disabling all the new modules and use default theme of Magento.